# Why there are different animation when performing hamburger to arrow animation on toolbar?

Tags: android

I have 2 different apps, which will perform hamburger to arrow animation on toolbar.

Both app are using `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'`

### First app - Simple hamburger to arrow animation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0-vmhOQPB0&feature=youtu.be

### Second app - Hamburger to arrow, with rotation animation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DljB0rskWE&feature=youtu.be

What really confused me is that, why there are 2 different animation. Both app are using same support library, with same animation code.

```
private static class ActionBarDrawerToggleEx extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle {
    public ActionBarDrawerToggleEx(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout,
                                   Toolbar toolbar, @StringRes int openDrawerContentDescRes,
                                   @StringRes int closeDrawerContentDescRes) {
        super(activity, drawerLayout, toolbar, openDrawerContentDescRes, closeDrawerContentDescRes);
    }

    public void enableAnimation(boolean enable) {
        enableAnimation = enable;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, enableAnimation ? slideOffset : 0);
    }

    private volatile boolean enableAnimation = true;
}

private void animateHamburgerToArrow() {
    actionBarDrawerToggle.enableAnimation(true);

    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
    anim.addListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            actionBarDrawerToggle.enableAnimation(false);
            arrowVisible = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

        }
    });

    anim.addUpdateListener(valueAnimator -> {
        float slideOffset = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onDrawerSlide(null, slideOffset);
    });
    anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    // You can change this duration to more closely match that of the default animation.
    anim.setDuration(300);
    anim.start();
}
```

Any idea why same code will yield different animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I had figured out. The difference in animation, is caused by this style.

```
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">false</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyApp.Base.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
```